# How to display success message using the Contact Form plugin

Tags: plugin-contactform

Kind of feel silly having to ask this but I cannot for the life of me get a success message to display after the redirect when the Contact Form submits.

I just am not sure how to call it in the template view.

I have tried various things like this:

```
{% set success = craft.config.get('successFlashMessage', 'contactform') %}

{% if success %}
  <div class="resp"><h3>{{ success }}</h3></div>
{% endif %}
```

But just cannot seem to grab it.

I did look at the documentation on Github and was not able to find it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use flash and not a redirect hidden input? https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#redirecting-after-submit

Comment: No, I just cannot get it to display a message either way, I would like it to stay on the same page but it does not absolutely have to.

Comment: So you're saying even if you add a `<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="success">`, you don't get redirected to `/success`?

Comment: The redirect works fine, but there is no message, sorry if it is unclear what I was asking, I am trying to figure out how to display a "your message has been sent" type message on the screen when the message has been successfully sent.

Comment: Ahh, if you're redirecting to a "success" template, then you can just hard code the "your message has been sent" message into the template. If there was a problem sending the email, the user is going to get an error page (either one supplied by you or a default Craft one)

Comment: Right, I really wanted to just flash the message, remove the form and possibly add the name though and keep them on the same page.  It's really not a big deal, I just seemed like one of those things that I thought would be simple at first and then I got totally bogged down doing and wanted to figure it out.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit your form? Or are you just redirecting to the same page upon submission?

Answer (score 4):

You can see in the [code for the plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/blob/master/contactform/controllers/ContactFormController.php#L148) that it sets a 'notice':

```
craft()->userSession->setNotice($settings->successFlashMessage);
```

As the [official documentation](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#setNotice-detail) mentions, this can later be grabbed with the following code:

```
{% set message = craft.session.getFlash('notice') %}
```

Then used as a normal message thereafter.

```
{{ message }}
```

Comment: Are there new URLs for the referenced links, here?